# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: element not interactable

Tags: capybara, hidden-field, google-chrome-headless

I need to select a colour in my acceptance tests. The hidden colour field is rendered with [`jquery-minicolors@2.1.10`](https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/). I use the following code to set the colour:

```
find('#colour', visible: false).set('#fefacb')
```

I use `capybara (3.11.1)`, `selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)` and `ChromeDriver 2.44.609545 (c2f88692e98ce7233d2df7c724465ecacfe74df5)`. I run the tests in headless mode

But my test fails with:

```
element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.1 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
```

What is wrong with my code? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like a user wouldn't be able to, you can't interact (set, click, etc) with non-visible fields.  Instead you need to interact with the visible elements on the page created by `jquery-minicolors` -- What those elements would be is completely dependent on how you've configured `jquery-minicolors` but should be relatively obvious by inspecting the page.